# React: Need to update className of element in array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm creating an app where I need to update the classname of an element when clicked on. There are 3000 up these elements and they are maintained in an array in state.

Right now I'm doing this below and it works, but should I be using setState? Nothing is added or removed from the array, only a change in className (btw, the addColorHandler is not in the same file as the state)

```
    addColorHandler = (e) => {
        let clicked = e.target
        if (this.state.color !== null) {
          clicked.className = this.state.color 
        }
    }
```

```
    state = {
        bulbs: 3496,
        display: []
```

if I should be using setState, how would I access the clicked element in the array and change it's class? I can't begin to figure out how the syntax would look.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    color: null,
    selectedColor: null
  }

  addColorHandler = (e) => {
    let clicked = e.target
    console.log(clicked)
    if (this.state.color !== null) {
      clicked.className = this.state.color
    }
  }

  changeColorHandler = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.className) {
      case('color red-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb red', selectedColor: 'red-peg'})
        break
      case('color blue-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb blue', selectedColor: 'blue-peg'})
        break
      case('color green-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb green', selectedColor: 'green-peg'})
        break
      case('color orange-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb orange', selectedColor: 'orange-peg'})
        break
      case('color yellow-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb yellow', selectedColor: 'yellow-peg'})
        break
      case('color pink-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb pink', selectedColor: 'pink-peg'})
        break
      case('color purple-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb purple', selectedColor: 'purple-peg'})
        break
      case('color white-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb white', selectedColor: 'white-peg'})
        break
      case('clear-peg'):
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb clear', selectedColor: 'clear-peg'})
        break
      default:
        this.setState({ color: 'bulb clear', selectedColor: 'clear-peg'})
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Display color={ this.state.color } addColor={ this.addColorHandler}/>
        <ColorBoard
          color = { this.state.color }
          selectedColor = { this.state.selectedColor }
          changeColor={ this.changeColorHandler }
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

```
class Display extends Component {
  state = {
    bulbs: 3496,
    display: []
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.createDisplay()
  }

  createDisplay = () => {

    const displayBoard = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.bulbs; i++) {
      displayBoard.push(
        <Light
          key={i}
          addColor={ this.props.addColor }
          color ={ this.props.color }
        />
      )
    }
    this.setState({display: displayBoard})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide more code samples so I can help you. Meanwhile, what I can tell you is to add a **KEY** or an **ID** to your components so we can find which one was clicked.

Example:

```
list = [
 {item: 'a', id:'1'}
]

const Example = list => {
 onClickHandler = e => {
  console.log(e.target.id)
 }

 const render = list.map(item => (
  <div id={item.id} onClick={onClickHandler}> {item.item} </div>
 )

 return ( <div> {render} </div> )
}
```

This might give you an idea. But you could also include the ID directly on the OnClick LIKE THIS: onClick={() => onClickHandler(item.id)}. However, depending on the size of your application it might cause some processing lost. Anyway, I hope it helps!

Bonus: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/react-js-passing-button-id-as-parameter-onclick-function/62301

Comment: I added the two files. I do assign a key to each element in the array when initializing it. Not sure how to access it though. I tried e.target.key and e.key and both come up undefined